# How to check the quality and brightness of a camera in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, camera, flutter-dependencies

Ii want to check the quality and the brightness of a camera while recording in a flutter.

Comment: Please provide a code snippet of what you have achieved so far.

Comment: i want to check the brightness of light before capturing the video. if the light is poor the i want to perform some actions .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.